# perl and whatsapp application

Tags: perl, whatsapp

We have an IT group on whatsapp where send messages for specific critical issues and we have some services  written on perl which send emails  using MIME::Lite to group of people ,we want to add some code to send also notifcation to group on whatsapp .
we searched on CPAN but didn't find any api that we can use to send notifcations using whatsapp on perl,

from initial reseach it seems that whatsapp using a customized xmpp but we didn't find any api on perl ,if someone has any example or done this on the past he are welcome to help thanks.

also worth to mention i found this library on github its writtern on php `https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI` but its not help us a lot as our service are written on perl.

Comment: Since it seems to use an extended XMPP API you may be able to get [Net::XMPP](http://p3rl.org/Net::XMPP) to work as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like WhatApp API exists for Perl, there are however traces that somebody could be working on it. Namespace `WhatApp` was registered in May last year, here is a corresponding PAUSE message: [Module submission WhatsApp](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.modules/2013/05/msg86089.html)

On the other hand the repository on GitHub is empty: [p5-whatsapp-api](https://github.com/dvinciguerra/p5-whatsapp-api)

There's also Python solution available: [yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup)

If it's absolutely necessary that it has to be Perl you might want to browse Python one and try to achieve the same in Perl, doesn't have to be full functionality that Python API has but only parts that you will use. I'd contact the person that registered the namespace @ CPAN and try to check if he has done anything so far, or try to build my own solution and upload to CPAN if I absolutely needed it in Perl.

Or... Check out [Inline::Python](http://search.cpan.org/~nine/Inline-Python-0.43/Python.pod) :)

Comment: It's actually quite rare for someone to register a namespace on PAUSE. Most people just upload a module which automatically restricts uploads for the namespace from other people.